# rails - bundle --deployment without development test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rspec, capistrano

I have a rails project and I have `rspec` tests for all controllers and models, recently I have made some changes and I added `carrierwave` image upload as a feature to an existing controller, so now I try to deploy my project via `capistrano` but I get:

```
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/comp/htdocs/master/my-project/releases/20131202113037; true"
    servers: ["app.stage.comp.net"]
    [app.stage.comp.net] executing command
    command finished in 2561ms
failed: "env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3@my-project' -c 'cd /var/www/comp/htdocs/master/my-project/releases/20131202113037 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/comp/htdocs/master/my-project/releases/20131202113037/Gemfile --path /var/www/comp/htdocs/master/my-project/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on app.stage.comp.net
```

Why I get this failure? is it because I didn't write `rspec` test for this recent feature?
How can I get ride of this?

BTW: there is no failure in `rspec` tests.

Comment: it is not refer to `rspec` at all! Have you commit and push updated `Gemfile.lock`? If - yes, try to enter server and run `bundle install --deployment --quiet --without development test` there - do you have error?

Comment: Thanks, I was not pushing the updated `Gemfile.lock`. I also added `carrirwave` test.. will update the post later on.

Answer (score 1):

As gotva mentioned in the comment, I was not pushing the updated `Gemfile.lock`. I also setup `Rspec` and `FactoryGirl` for testing Carrierwave uploaders via below link:

http://icebergist.com/posts/rspec-and-factorygirl-setup-for-testing-carrierwave-uploaders